# Limit of a sequence approaching infinity involving (-1)^n

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having a hard time determining whether this sequence converges or not as n approaches infinity, I don't really know how to approach it because I am under the impression it diverges due to the oscillation of $(-1)^n$, but beyond that I'm unsure, any hint or help is appreciated.

$$ x_n = (-1)^n \lvert n-3 \rvert $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $|x_n| \to \infty$, then $x_n$ diverges.

Comment: Or, put another way, if $x_n$ converges, then so does $|x_n|,$ by continuity of the absolute value function.

Comment: Ahh I see how to get it now, thank you!

Comment: Would I also be able to use the limit property of sequences of multiplication to split the limit into two limits with $(-1)^n$ and $\lvert n-3 \rvert$ ?

Comment: You have to be careful doing that. For example, $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $y_n = n$. Then $y_n$ clearly diverges, but $z_n = x_ny_n = 1$ does not

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence converges, then every subsequence must converge to the same value. However: $$x_{2n} = |2n - 3| \\ x_{2n + 1} = - |2n - 2| $$
One goes to $+\infty$ and the other goes to $-\infty $. The sequence must diverge. In fact, it would suffice to show that **one** subsequence diverges. But this strategy of finding different values might be useful for other problems, so I wanted to show you anyway.

Comment: Very interesting way to approach it I hadn't seen before, thank you.